# IN query in MYSQL Function

Tags: mysql

I m in a situation where i need pass comma separated project ids from a Stored Procedure to a Function

Stored Procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spGetData`(
)
BEGIN

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000000;
set @leadProjectIDs = (SELECT distinct cast(group_concat(ProjectID separator ',')
                     as  char(10000000))
                    from
                    project pr where Status = 2);

select fnCount(@leadProjectIDs) as Count;
END
```

And Function is

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fnCount`(
                 _projectIds varchar(800)
       ) RETURNS decimal(10,2)
 Begin

   Set @LeadsCount = (Select count(*) from project where projectid in(_projectIds));
   return @LeadsCount;
END
```

But above function not return any count.

The SP and Function i mentioned here are just for example, i m using Function to get data because its has many more conditions and join then mentioned here.

So just want to know, How can i pass projectids like 1,2,3,4 and get result from a Function in MYSQL.

Comment: Is it just me or you call `fnCount` and create the function `fnGetPSLeadCount1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `INSTR` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fnCount`(
                 _projectIds varchar(800)
       ) RETURNS decimal(10,2)
 Begin

   Set @LeadsCount = (Select count(*) 
                        from project 
                       where INSTR(_projectIds, concat(',', projectid, ',')) > 0);
   return @LeadsCount;
END
```

Just be sure the every projectid inside the _projectIds parameter has the format `,projectid,`. Additionally, be aware that there will be a limit of project ids that could be concatenated on that string, it could blow up at some point.

Comment: I try INSTR  and it gives me this "27255", project ids passed are 12747,12754,12782,12906,12910,12972,13067,13068,13098,13118 not sure what is happening? i want total number of projects passed so if 10 in projectids then 10 must return. INSTR  Returns the position of the first occurrence of substring in string , so this will not work here

Comment: can we use dynamic query in MYSQL function like set _qry = (Select concat('Set LeadsCount = (Select count(*) from project where projectid in(',_projectIds,'))'));
    PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
    EXECUTE stmt; or some other way

Comment: It should work, it would be INSTR(',12747,12754,12782,12906,12910,12972,13067,13068,13098,13118,',projectid). It would return more than 0 only for those that he finds on the string.

Comment: i m getting same value 27255. 27255 is total number of records in Project table. So it is not matching exactly to the project id

Comment: Did you use the  `concat(',', projectid, ',')` for the instr? Do all the project ids on the string are with `,` on the sides?

Comment: yes i did same, Select count(*) from project where INSTR(',12747,12754,12782,12906,12910,12972,13067,13068,13098,13118,', concat(',',projectid, ',') > 0)

Comment: Its missing a parenthesis after the concat: Select count(*) from project where INSTR(',12747,12754,12782,12906,12910,12972,13067,13068,13098,13118,', concat(',',projectid, ',')) > 0

Comment: It was my fault, it was missing on the answer too, i updated it. You're welcome.